# Show field based on selection (JS)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to show fields based on what is selected in menu select option.

I tried some JS with the help of other posts found here on Stackoverflow, but failed.

I'm a fan, i dont know js well, i hope to find help with this question. Thanks to everyone for any answers, I leave the info below.

1. I would like to show the result of this:
   var dayli_intake_mass = ((+ target) / 100 * (+ tdee) + (+ tdee));
   only when mass1, mass2 or mass3 is selected.

Otherwise

2. I would like to show the result of this:
   var dayli_intake_def = ((+ tdee) - (+ target) / 100 * (+ tdee));
   only when def1, def2 or def3 is selected.

So, the mass1, mass2 and mass3 selection should show dayli_intake_mass

While the selection def1, def2 and def3 should show dayli_intake_def

Point 1 is an addition, point 2 is a subtraction. I don't want both to be visible, but only one of the two fields based on the selection.

I apologize for the bad English :(

```
<div class="fieldcontainer">
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="4" id="tdee" name"tdee" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo TDEE" form="fbday" required autocomplete="off"/>
<label>Spesa calorica</label>
</div>

<div class="container_level">
  <select class="target" id="target_select" form="fbday" name="target">
    <option value="0">Stile di vita / Attività fisica</option>
    <option id="mass1" name="radsa" value="5">mass1</option>
    <option id="mass2" name="radsa" value="10">mass2</option>
    <option id="mass3" name="radsa" value="15">mass3</option>
    <option id="def1" name="radsa" value="10">def1</option>
    <option id="def2" name="radsa" value="15">def2</option>
    <option id="def3" name="radsa" value="20">def3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<!---Fabbisogno Giornaliero--->

<div id="fbbday0" class="results" hidden>
<input type="text" form="fbday" class="result-field" id="dayli_intake_mass" name="dayli_intake"
placeholder="Fabbisogno giornaliero / 0.000 Kcal" min="1" readonly/>
<label class="mts-label"></label>
</div>

<div id="fbbday1" class="results" hidden>
<input type="text" form="fbday" class="result-field" id="dayli_intake_def" name="dayli_intake"
placeholder="Fabbisogno giornaliero / 0.000 Kcal" min="1" readonly/>
<label class="mts-label"></label>
</div>

<form action="" id="fbday">
</form>

<button name="calculate" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
<button id="reset" onclick="resetFields()">Reset</button>
```

```
calculate = function()
{
    var tdee = document.getElementById('tdee').value;
    var target = document.querySelector('#target_select option:checked').value;
    
    var dayli_intake_mass = ((+target)/100*(+tdee)+(+tdee));
    var kcal = "Devi assumere "+dayli_intake_mass.toLocaleString('it-IT',{maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal"; document.getElementById('dayli_intake_mass').value = kcal;
    
    var dayli_intake_def = ((+tdee)-(+target)/100*(+tdee));
    var kcal = "Devi assumere "+dayli_intake_def.toLocaleString('it-IT',{maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + " Kcal"; document.getElementById('dayli_intake_def').value = kcal;
    
//This is Target Radio Selection//
 var mass1 = document.getElementById('mass1').value;
 var mass2 = document.getElementById('mass2').value;
 var mass3 = document.getElementById('mass3').value;
 var def1 = document.getElementById('def1').value;
 var def2 = document.getElementById('def2').value;
 var def3 = document.getElementById('def3').value;    

//This is HideShow Result//
var conditional = document.querySelector('#target_select option:checked').value;
document.getElementById('dayli_intake_mass').hidden = conditional !== '5';
document.getElementById('dayli_intake_mass').hidden = conditional !== '10';
document.getElementById('dayli_intake_mass').hidden = conditional !== '15';
document.getElementById('dayli_intake_def').hidden = conditional !== '10';
document.getElementById('dayli_intake_def').hidden = conditional !== '15';
document.getElementById('dayli_intake_def').hidden = conditional !== '20';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/snake93/w1nLbhxv/81/

Answer (score 0):

## Edited

- you can use `change` event to handle that
- when you select one of the list it's will call `change` event then check or execute your code
- because of there's some values like each other for example `mass2` value = 10 and also `def1` value = 10 .
- because of that you can't only compare the values but also you need to compare the element id so i added the id's in the comparison operation

> Here's the code

```
var target_select = document.getElementById("target_select");

target_select.addEventListener("change", function () {
  var tdee = document.getElementById('tdee').value;
  var target = document.querySelector('#target_select option:checked');
  var fbbday1 = document.getElementById('fbbday1'),
  fbbday0 = document.getElementById('fbbday0')

  var dayli_intake_mass = ((+target.value)/100*(+tdee)+(+tdee));
  var dayli_intake_def = ((+tdee)-(+target.value)/100*(+tdee));
  
    //This is Target Radio Selection//
 var mass1 = document.getElementById('mass1').value;
 var mass2 = document.getElementById('mass2').value;
 var mass3 = document.getElementById('mass3').value;
 var def1 = document.getElementById('def1').value;
 var def2 = document.getElementById('def2').value;
 var def3 = document.getElementById('def3').value;
 var massArr = [mass1, mass2, mass3],
 deffArr = [def1, def2, def3]

    if(massArr.indexOf(this.value) != -1 && target.id === 'mass1' || target.id === 'mass2' || target.id === 'mass3') {
        fbbday0.removeAttribute('hidden')
        document.getElementById('dayli_intake_mass').value = dayli_intake_mass;
    } else {
        fbbday0.setAttribute('hidden', true)
    }
    if(deffArr.indexOf(this.value) != -1 && target.id === 'def1' || target.id === 'def2' || target.id === 'def3') {
        fbbday1.removeAttribute('hidden')
        document.getElementById('dayli_intake_def').value = dayli_intake_def;
    } else {
        fbbday1.setAttribute('hidden', true)
    }
});
```

Comment: I try to explain better

1. I would like to show the result of this:
var dayli_intake_mass = ((+ target) / 100 * (+ tdee) + (+ tdee));
only when mass1, mass2 or mass3 is selected.

Otherwise

2. I would like to show the result of this:
var dayli_intake_def = ((+ tdee) - (+ target) / 100 * (+ tdee));
only when def1, def2 or def3 is selected.

So, the mass1, mass2 and mass3 selection should show dayli_intake_mass

While the selection def1, def2 and def3 should show dayli_intake_def

I apologize for the bad English :(

Comment: Thank you for your time. The recommended code works fine, however I wanted to keep the button calculate (although not important) and the descriptions before and after the calculation result. In any case, I will treasure your advice and try to adapt it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

First, I edited the values of the `select` options to be as below:

```
<select class="target" id="target_select" form="fbday" name="target" (onChange)="showHideIntake($event)">
<option value="0">Stile di vita / Attività fisica</option>
<option id="mass1" name="radsa" value="5">mass1</option>
<option id="mass2" name="radsa" value="10">mass2</option>
<option id="mass3" name="radsa" value="15">mass3</option>
<option id="def1" name="radsa" value="-10">def1</option>
<option id="def2" name="radsa" value="-15">def2</option>
<option id="def3" name="radsa" value="-20">def3</option>
</select>
```

Second, I added an event called `(onChange)` to the `select` element as shown in the first line in the previous point.

Third, I added an `eventListener` to the `select` element to handle the `(onChange)` event, as below:

```
const target_select = document.querySelector('#target_select');
const dayli_intake_mass = document.querySelector('#dayli_intake_mass');
const dayli_intake_def = document.querySelector('#dayli_intake_def');
target_select.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  console.log(+event.target.value); // just for checking selected option
  // the + (plus sign) is to convert from string to number
  dayli_intake_mass.hidden = dayli_intake_def.hidden = true;
  event.target.value > 0 ? dayli_intake_mass.hidden = false : 
  dayli_intake_def.hidden = false;
});
```

With this, `dayli_intake_mass` and `dayli_intake_def` are shown or hidden upon the `select` option. Plus, you can use the value of the `select` option directly upon select one option of them.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I tried to play around with your code a bit, but I don't quite understand how to introduce it. It gives me a series of errors like 'daily_intake_mass has' already been decleared. The same is for daily_intake_def

Also, dayli_intake_def.hidden = false;
provides the following message: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

Where am I wrong?